# Drag and drop for specific location?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am trying to integrate drag and drop in ma app. In ma app i need to move text anywhere within the single layout (Relative Layout) . How to get the end drag point where  is user  want to place.  is there any method available?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this and customize it for your own needs:
https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid

Comment: I want to text move anywhere .only one text i should use